# First Try On A Rebus Puzzle

Tags: visual, rebus

  1.

[image]

+the other word for
[image]

2.[image]
+ The middle of

[image]

3.

[image]

+

[image]

Hint :

> The number of faces that appear in question 2 is unimportant
>  I am looking for a 1 word answer in question 2

Comment: Gonna try a rebus puzzle. Suggestions and feedbacks are welcome :)

Comment: Just added another hint for number 2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My answers are:

1.

> YouTube

2.

> Headset

3.

> Facebook

Comment: Correct Answer :))

Comment: Ah. I was thinking of faces all the time, not the head.

Answer (score 2):

Is 2nd one

> Pencil set? First one is created with pencil and middle of the second image is a set.

Comment: Nope. It's actually a thing that many people use in their lives. Try looking at the hint. BTW, Rot 13 (Gur frpbaq jbeq va lbhe frpbaq nafjre vf pbeerpg)

Comment: @KevinL I guess I now have to get the clue from the first image only.

Comment: Might be rot13([JrPung](https://www.wechat.com/))?

Comment: Wrong answer @RickvanOsta. As I said in my hint, the number of faces does not matter.

Answer (score 2):

Is number 2 -

> Facet. (face + set) => facet

Comment: That's actually quite close. Rot 13 (svefg jbeq jebat)